Anchor Test Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')
I am current trying to build a solana calculator project on my mac(M3 version), mostly duplicate the code what I learned on Udemy. So basically I am trying run the same of the teacher on my pc successfully.
What I use:

Anchor
Mocha
node_modules/@project-serum
solana

What I did:

Use anchor init to create a project
Anchor build(I can build without errors)
Add some code to lib.rs file:

    use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

    declare_id!("CfaDqW3stWavnEn8KZLnqSLbmTzUjhn3aNawSCtsVbGu");

    #[program]
    pub mod mycalculatordapp {
        use super::*;
        pub fn create(ctx: Context<Create>, init_message: String) -> Result<()> {
            let calculator = &mut ctx.accounts.calculator;
            calculator.greeting = init_message;
            Ok(())
        }
     }

    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct Create<'info>{
        #[account(init, payer=user, space=264)]
        pub calculator: Account<'info, Calculator>,
        #[account(mut)]
       pub user: Signer<'info>,
       pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
    }

    #[account]
    pub struct Calculator {
        pub greeting: String,
        pub result: i64,
        pub remainder: i64
    }


Add a simple test code to mycalculatordapp.ts file:

const assert = require('assert');
const anchor = require('@project-serum/anchor');
const { SystemProgram } = anchor.web3;

describe('mycalculatordapp', () => {
  const provider = anchor.Provider.local();
});

And then I got this Error when I run 'anchor test' on my terminal:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/tests/mycalculatordapp.ts:6:36)
    at Object.create (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:148:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:42:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/tests/mycalculatordapp.ts:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:60:20)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:103:20)
    at singleRun (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at Object.exports.handler (/Users/chester/Desktop/dev/mycalculatordapp/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:374:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.

I have tried my ways but just can't not solve this issue, hope some professionals can take a look and give me a insight.
I have check all the dependencies, which should be installed correctly. The problem will be very likely to caused by this line:
const provider = anchor.Provider.local();
I am not sure is there a environmental set up error of any other issue, just can't pass this.
